# Refreshing partial view via ajax call is hanging app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

MVC5 app I am refreshing a partial view every 5 seconds however after a few minutes or so the app is hanging with clientside browser error of

> net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

The code to call the partial is here

```
 function setupRefresh() {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    // ajax load partial view
    $("#PartialViewPlaceHolder").load("/testController/GetTestPartialView");
    // refresh count every 5 seconds
    $(function() {
        window.setInterval(setupRefresh, 5000);
    });

   }
```

The code for my partial is

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
    @if (Model.TestCount > 0)
    {

            <p class="alert alert-info">
                There are <strong>@Model.testCount</strong> widgets in this batch
            </p>
            @ShowButton()

    }
    else
    {
        <p class="alert alert-info">
            There are no widgets
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

```
 @helper ShowButton()
```

> {
>       @Html.ActionLink("Do something", "GetPartialView", "TestController", new {@class = "modal-link btn btn-primary btn-lg
>   btn-block"}) }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this fragment must be outside of setupRefresh()

```
$(function() {
        window.setInterval(setupRefresh, 5000);
    });
```